# angularjs context root variable example

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

We are using angular js and spring mvc and jsp as the templates. We would like to access context root variable(pageContext.request.contextPath) in angular js module. Does anyone know how can we access this? A good working example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a $location service in angular which represents the URL as set of methods. You can use this service to get the url details.

Say you have to do this in a directive, below is a simple example

```
(function(){
"use strict";
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('myExample', myExample);

myExample.$inject = ['$location', '$log']

function myExample($location, $log) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'app/feature/example.directive.html',
        controller: ExampleController,
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    };

    return directive;
}

function ExampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.path = $location.path();
    $log.info(vm.path());
}
})();
```

Comment: how would you inject this location provider in angular config and use it in state provider?

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject $location into config function as only providers and constants can be injected to config block.  I am not pretty sure on your requirement. But you can inject them into run blocks.

```
angular.module('app',[])
    .config(function(injectables){
//inject providers and constants
    })
    .run(function(inject $location){
//inject $location
});
```

The below link gives a short explanation on config and run blocks

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module